# Loading Django static files via Apache

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, centos7

I know there are dozens of this questions around and I think I've read all of them, but couldn't find my problem.

I've created a file named `/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf` and this is what I've written in it:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    Alias /media/  /var/www/html/igame/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/igame/static/
    <Directory /var/www/html/igame/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/igame/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/igame/igame/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/html/igame/igame>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess igame python-path=/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup igame

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my static settings in `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = True 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

I've ran `python3.6 manage.py collectstatic`.

But when I run the project by `python3.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, the statics files does not load on my project.

I use `python 3.6` plus `django 2.1`and `Apache 5.4`.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I installed `mod_wsgi` and added these lines to `httpd.conf` as [this documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) suggests:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/igame/igame/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/html/igame/igame>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/djangoenv
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/igame
WSGIDaemonProcess igame python-home=/var/www/html/djangoenv python-path=/var/www/html/igame
WSGIProcessGroup igame
```

And removed this lines from `django.conf`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess igame python-home=/var/www/html/djangoenv python-path=/var/www/html/igame
WSGIProcessGroup igame
```

I normally do this with `nginx` and now I'm really confused how to make it work with Apache.

Comment: Why are you running both Apache and the dev server together? Which endpoint are you testing? Port 80 for apache, or port 8000 for dev server?

Comment: @YuvalAdam  Apache is running on port 80. I got some wordpress projects on `ip.ip.ip.ip.:8009`. So I had to send django project on port 8000. I have centos 7 on my server.

Comment: You don't need to run them both. I suggest you read the documentation on how to deploy with Apache https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: @YuvalAdam I installed mod_wsgi and followed the documents you've linked. I still can't have static files loaded. should I remove my `django.conf` file? I normally do this by `nginx`. But this one I have to make it work with Apache